# Script not working in cell in every row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cells

I have a row/column table with switches, unfortunately the script can't find

the switches in the new column, basically after the end of the cell .

I tried modifying some of the scripts that were posted in the similar posts but
none of them worked. I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Here's my HTML and the java script that does the calculation for the switches:

```
    <div style="margin-left:-178px">
      <form action="file:///Users/jason/Desktop/Temp/JACK010.txt" target="_blank">
        <font color="white">JACK010</font>
        <input type="submit" value="CHECK ADDRESS">
          <div id="checkbox-container">
            <div style="margin-left:178px">
              <div style="margin-top:-18px">
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="option170">
                </div>
      </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have a lot of those, within the cell, and finally the JavaScript:

```
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: "I have a lot of those"...a lot of what, exactly? That whole HTML? Or some part of it? What do you regard to be the "new column", exactly? Please be clear, we are not privy to your whole application or the workings of your mind. All we can see is what is in front of us, and your words do not relate very well to the code.

Comment: Please be more complete, e.g. I see `</td>` but no opening `<td>`, same for `<tr>` and for various `<div>`s. With faulty/incomplete HTML it is hard to guess what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using only `$("#checkbox-container :checkbox");` results in only reading the first container with the ID `checkbox-container`.

If you want to fetch all checkboxes, you should either change the `checkbox-container` to a class or use the following selector within jQuery:

```
var $checkboxes = $("div#checkbox-container :checkbox");
```

It will then loop through all the checkboxes, even if an ID is used instead of a class.

Keep in mind, that the ID of your checkbox (`<input type="checkbox" id="option170">`) must however change in order to get valid data and all the values you want.

*Side note: Please keep your HTML code clean and valid.*

Comment: Thank you Sir! I'll keep that in mind. It works with the divider.